# Is there a way to check if my tokens are unlocked or not without paying gas fees?

Tags: blockchain, smart-contract-wallets, binance-smart-chain

Is there a way to check if my tokens are unlocked or not without paying gas fees?
Like if I can interact with the smart contract with its current state without sending a request on the mainnet.
Edit: the token are not stacked. I was given the tokens.

Comment: Welcome, @hakim47. Could you explain what's the context here? Are your tokens staked in a contract or vested or anything of the sort?

Comment: @scorpion9979 no token are not stacked. I was given the tokens. currently every time I want to check if the to tokens are unlocked I try to transfer them.

Comment: could you share the token contract's address? There might be a public read-only function that shows if they're unlocked.

Comment: @scorpion9979, Okay here it is 0x53035E4e14fb3f82C02357B35d5cC0C5b53928B4 , link to bscscan https://bscscan.com/token/0x53035e4e14fb3f82c02357b35d5cc0c5b53928b4

Comment: Ok. So I think you need to call `getRoundBalances` from https://bscscan.com/address/0x53035e4e14fb3f82c02357b35d5cc0c5b53928b4#readContract using you wallet address as input.
You should get the amount of tokens you're allowed to spend appended with 18 decimal places.